# Count total number of matches in directory with ag

Tags: full-text-search, ag

I'm attempting to find the number of matches for a given string across a large project. Currently, to do this with `ag` I am using the following command:

```
$ echo 0$(ag -c searchterm | sed -e "s/^.*:/+/") | bc
```

which is obviously a bit lengthy and not very intuitive. Is there any better way to get the total number of matches in a directory from `ag`? I've dug through the documentation and couldn't find anything helpful there.

Edit: Thanks to a [recent commit](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/commit/df5d456b355f0ffaceef63aeba92dfa3e413571b) to `ag`, the filenames can be stripped with `ag` instead of `sed`, so this also works:

```
$ echo `ag test -c --nofilename | sed "s/$/+/"`0 | bc
```

Note: I realize I could do this with `ack -hcl searchterm` (Well, almost. In my specific case I'd need an `--ignore-dir building` in there as well), but as this is already a large project (and will be growing considerably), the speed boost offered by `ag` makes it preferable (`ack` takes about 3 seconds for my searches vs `ag`'s nearly instantaneous result), so I would like to stick with it.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: @jjaderberg Not exactly. The best option seems to be the `--stats` option followed by parsing out the correct line. (e.g., `ag --stats searchterm | tail -n 5 | head -n 1`). I also submitted a pull request for a `--stats-only` option which prevents anything else from being printed, in that case `ag --stats searchterm | head -n 1` would get the number of matches. In both those cases you'd still need to filter out " matches" to get just the number though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use ag itself to match the stats. E.g.:

```
 >$ ag --stats --java -c 'searchstring' | ag '.*matches'
 >$ 22 matches 
 >$ 6 files contained matches
```

Filter with lookahead to print just the number of matches:

```
 >$ ag --stats --java -c 'searchstring' | ag -o '^[0-9]+(?=\smatches)'
 >$ 22
```

Comment: For those finding this now, the `--stats-only` option was added in https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/pull/733

Comment: while better ```--stats-only``` still leaves one needing to filter out the cruff commentary (e.g. "xyz bytes searched") to get just the raw number of matches; for pipe chains and scripts, this is often what one needs.

Comment: True. However, the original answer fails if the search string contains the word "matches".  `ag --stats-only 'searchstring' | ag '.*matches$'` won't have that issue (note the trailing `$` too).

Answer (score 6):

`ag -o --nofilename --nobreak 'searchstring' | wc -l`

- `-o` prints each match individually
- `--nofilename` removes filenames from output
- `--nobreak` removes newlines between matches in different files

Answer (score 5):

Still no great solution, but here's what I've managed to come up with thusfar for anyone else who finds this:

If you're not searching huge amounts of files, just use `ack -hcl searchterm`, otherwise...

I have been able to improve the command in my question by leveraging the `--stats` option, which appends something like the following to the search results:

```
714 matches
130 files contained matches
300 files searched
123968435 bytes searched
0.126203 seconds
```

For manual use, that's good enough (though it still floods the screen with all the matches), but for scripts I still need just the number. So, to that end, I've gone from the command in my question down to this:

```
$ ag --stats searchterm | tail -n5 | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f1
```

or the more succinct but less memorable

```
$ ag --stats searchterm | tac | awk 'NR==5 {print $1}'
```

(replace `tac` with `tail -r` if you don't have `tac`)

To save a bit more typing, I aliased the latter half of the command so I can just pipe `ag --stats` to my alias and get what I want. So, with `alias agmatches='tac | awk "NR==5 {print \$1}'` I can get just the matches by running `ag --stats searchterm | agmatches`.

Still would be much better if these was something built into ag to help facilitate this. I submitted a pull request for a `--stats-only` output option that would help, <s>but nothing has come of that yet</s> which is available if you build directly from the repo, but isn't yet in a stable release, so that should speed up the process a tidbit for large numbers of results.

Answer (score 3):

I like gregory's answer above, but to add some more context:

> ag --stats --java -c 'searchstring' | ag '.*matches'

- The `--java` flag indicates that `ag` will only search for files with `.java` (and `.properties`) [extensions](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/doc/ag.1.md#file-types). So if you were searching within a python project for `.py` files, you would use the `--python` flag. Run the `ag --list-file-types` command for all the file types available for searching.
- The `-c` or `--count` flag provides the [number of matches](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/doc/ag.1.md#options).